# Help Needed Statisitcs

Tags: statistics

[image]

Can someone explain to me where they are getting -2.58 and 2.58? Is it in the z distribution tables and if so how can I find it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it by looking in [this z-table](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf) for the entry .0049 (close enough to .005).  Notice that the row is -2.5 and the column is 0.08 which corresponds to -2.58.

Basically you are trying to put 99% probability in the middle which means .5% probability in the left tail (because the normal is symmetric).

Answer (score 1):

$2.58$ is a **critical value** for the standard normal distribution corresponding to the stated significance level of $\alpha = 0.01 = 1\%$ for the test.  Specifically, it is the value for which $$\Pr[|Z| > 2.57583] \approx 0.01,$$ where $Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 0, \sigma^2 = 1)$.

In terms of the figure shown in the solution, what this means is that the area under the bell curve in the two tails (that is, the area under the curve for values larger than $2.58$ and smaller than $-2.58$) is approximately $0.01$ or $1\%$ of the total area under the curve.  Because the value of the test statistic you calculated is less than $-2.58$, this means the probability that you could have obtained the data you did, assuming that the supposition that the true proportion is $p = 0.45$, is smaller than $1\%$, which means there is considerable evidence to suggest that this supposition is incorrect; hence the true proportion is unlikely to be $0.45$.

---

How do we calculate such critical values for a given $\alpha$?  Note that if the test is **two-sided**, then what we want is $$z_{\alpha/2}^* = \Phi^{-1}(1 - \alpha/2),$$ where $$\Phi(z) = F_Z(z) = \Pr[Z \le z] = \int_{t = -\infty}^z \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t^2/2} \, dt$$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution, and gives us the probability that a standard normal random variable is less than or equal to $z$.  So the inverse CDF is the **quantile** function, and we call the critical value $z_{\alpha/2}^*$ the **upper $100 \alpha/2$ percentile** of the standard normal distribution.  Tables of common critical values are given for various $\alpha$ levels and are also found in normal distribution tables.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.had2know.com/academics/normal-distribution-probability-calculator.html).

For $\mu (mean) = 0$, $\sigma (standard\ deviation) = 1$, X1 = -2.58 and X2=2.58, you get an area under the curve as ~99%

Here, X1 and X2 are points (in terms of standard deviations) on x-axis between which the area is computed.